# Unknown Cause of SPF Fail

Tags: email, ip, spam, spf, dmarc

I have the following SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.mailspamprotection.com include:_spf.google.com ip4:209.85.220.0/24 ~all
```

Although I have included _spf.mailspamprotection.com in my SPF record, which includes ip4:146.66.121.0/24, I get SPF Fail from delivery.mailspamprotection.com IP:146.66.121.100. I have the same issue with the following IP addresses from delivery.mailspamprotection.com.

```
146.66.121.63 
146.66.121.85
146.66.121.80
146.66.121.212
146.66.121.88
146.66.121.89
146.66.121.64
146.66.121.164
146.66.121.66
```

It is not clear what the cause of SPF Fail is.

Comment: It is hard to tell what happens here since information are missing. Where do you get the error, i.e which mail server is calculating an SPF Fail. Which domain is used as SMTP envelope, i.e. it is even the correct SPF record for the used domain?

Comment: Please send an email to check-auth@verifier.port25.com.  You will receive a report back showing why the SPF check failed.  Then, please edit the your question to append the report.

Comment: I only count eight DNS queries, so that should be under the ten lookup limit that could cause errors (unless you've omitted parts like `a mx`). As mti2935 noted above, we need more information to help you.